# CQL Cassandra Where clause

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

The following query (cqlsh cassandra)

```
SELECT * from keyspace.dialogs WHERE sid = 
"07323067ef605ffdb4fa" ;
```

gives me this error

```
SyntaxException: line 1:92 no viable alternative at input ';' 
(...keyspace.dialogs WHERE sid = 
["07323067ef605ffdb4fa" ;)
```

The sid key is correct, and the data should be there, is the syntax different with cqlsh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use singlequote for txt:

```
SELECT * from keyspace.dialogs WHERE sid = '07323067ef605ffdb4fa' ;
```